# Can I play GameCube audio through my mac computer or headphones?

Tags: pc, audio-hardware, nintendo-gamecube

I recently bought a Nintendo GameCube.

I connected it to my desktop monitor through a AV to HDMI converter, as the monitor does not have AV. However, the audio doesn't work, because my monitor has no built-in speakers.

I'd like to either play the sound through my Macbook Pro's speakers or through a pair of headphones. I'm assuming the former would be easier, as most headphones don't have volume control.

I tried purchasing [a simple adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00066HPUQ) online. This didn't work, and I'm assuming it's because the audio needs to be converted from analog to digital.

How do I route the sound from my GameCube into my MacBook speakers, or earphones?

Comment: This strikes me as a hardware recommendation question. Unfortunately these are off-topic to us and will most likely be closed. Sorry.

Comment: @Texenox okay sure, sorry about that. I'm obviously new to the site. Is there a different forum you'd recommend posting this question (stackexchange related or otherwise)?

Comment: It's probably not possible. Notebooks aren't designed to provide a screen or speaker for other devices, a Macbook will probably work even less. It would be easier if you bought some speakers and connected the audio directly to it, instead of via the HDMI adapter.

Comment: For the adapter you linked, you could try a [PS4 Gold wireless headset](http://www.amazon.com/PlayStation-Gold-Wireless-Stereo-Headset-4/dp/B00HVBPRUO/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1443124519&sr=1-1&keywords=ps4+gold+wireless+headset). It's compatible with PC and PS4 wirelessly, or pretty much everything that works with regular headphones using the wires.

Comment: Or you could use [this adapter](http://www.amazon.com/CablesOnline-Stereo-Splitter-Adapter-AV-Y14G/dp/B00EG1S5N8/ref=sr_1_24?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1443124644&sr=1-24&keywords=3.5+to+3.5+audio+female+female) instead. You can plug in just about any conventional headphone you like.

Comment: [Here's one adapter](http://www.amazon.com/Monoprice-107230-Stereo-Adaptor-Plated/dp/B004C87WQ6/ref=pd_sim_23_14?ie=UTF8&refRID=1T1KXZQTZTY8HASGEF3J) which should work with the adapter you've already bought. Sorry about all the comments, by the way.

Comment: @Nolonar that adapter doesn't appear to convert from analog to digital, which is what I need. The gamecube outputs analog audio but most speakers/headphones take in digital

Comment: How exactly is "how do I play GameCube sound through my computer" a hardware recommendation?

Comment: @user3772119 Speakers and headphones are inherently analogue devices and so most don't accept digital inputs.  (The ones that do have a converter and an amplifier builtin.) The reason why your adapter doesn't work is the GameCube's analogue audio is an unamplified line level output that isn't capable of driving most speakers and headphones directly at a volume level that can be easily heard.

Comment: @JasonBerkan I was referring to the first revision which was asking for recommendations of different sound devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with either with a headphone amplifier that accepts stereo analogue input, or a laptop with an analogue line in or microphone input (though the later is less than ideal.)

In the first case you'll need to either connect the GameCube's red and white RCA connectors on the end of its AV cable to the headphone amplifier directly or you'll need to use the adapter you've already bought.  In the second case you'll need to use your adapter to connect into the input on your laptop.  You'd then need to find the option in OS X that lets you monitor the line in or microphone input through your laptop's speaker. I don't have a Mac so I know where that would be.